# powershell escape from >>

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

i'm just getting into PowerShell and i've encountered this problem:
if i place the escape character (') or single quotation mark (") at the end of a command PowerShell enters into a suspend/whatever mode where there are ">>" on the left on the screen, instead of "PS C:>", i know that PS just expects more information/commands/whatever from me and that is why it is providing me with new lines and what-not, but how do i escape/stop that? Even after pressing "Enter" a few times, PS just provides me with more >>s, i want to end my input and finish the command, and so far i was unable to find any information on that, mostly because i don't even know what's it called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's waiting for a closing quote or brace `}`, so you can either enter one of those and press enter twice more, or use <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel the current command.

FYI:

```
' = literal quote (expects another single quote)
" = quotes to use when interpolating strings (expects another double quote)
` = escape character (continuation of the current line)
, = list separator (expects another list element)
{ = begin of script block (expects closing curly bracket)
```

As long as whatever you're doing is balanced, pressing enter twice will exit the block. You'd get another `>>` on the first press in case you wanted to start anything else, if not it will return you to the prompt.

Comment: oh, thanks, but can i use any quote at the end of a command in order to enter that mode and enter more lines of code, like  >if ($x -eq 2) {2}'  >>elseif (whatever){}  >>else{}'?

Comment: Updated the answer, it's waiting for a quote or curly brace most likely.